# Label alignment inside a wxButton

Tags: wxpython

I am trying to align a label inside a wxButton and using
`style=wx.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_LEFT`

```
self.button = wx.Button(id = -1,label='No. of Targets',parent=self.panel1, size=wx.Size(100, 30), style=wx.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_LEFT)
```

But it still shows the label in the center.

What is the correct method for left justifying button labels?

Comment: Was the answer provided not what you were after?

Comment: strange, that I never got notified about this. Yes, it does. I will check and get back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the button styles.(BU_LEFT, BU_RIGHT, BU_TOP, BU_BOTTOM)

```
import wx

class ButtonFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, value):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,None)
        self.btn1 = wx.Button(self, -1, ("Left"), size=(80,80),  style = wx.BU_LEFT)
        self.btn2 = wx.Button(self, -1, ("Center"), size=(80,80))
        self.btn3 = wx.Button(self, -1, ("Right"), size=(80,80), style = wx.BU_RIGHT)
        self.btn4 = wx.Button(self, -1, ("Top"), size=(80,80), style = wx.BU_TOP)
        self.btn5 = wx.Button(self, -1, ("Bottom"), size=(80,80), style = wx.BU_BOTTOM)

        self.btnSizer1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.btnSizer1.Add(self.btn1 , 0, wx.RIGHT, 10)
        self.btnSizer1.Add(self.btn2 , 0, wx.RIGHT, 10)
        self.btnSizer1.Add(self.btn3 , 0, wx.RIGHT, 10)

        self.btnSizer2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.btnSizer2.Add(self.btn4 , 0, wx.RIGHT, 10)
        self.btnSizer2.Add(self.btn5 , 0, wx.RIGHT, 10)

        self.btnSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.btnSizer.Add(self.btnSizer1)
        self.btnSizer.Add(self.btnSizer2)
        self.SetSizer(self.btnSizer)
        self.Centre()
        self.Show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    ButtonFrame(None)
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image]